# UI Layout problem/algorithm

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, layout

I am trying to solve a problem where i need to fit a set of rectangles(views) in a bigger rectangle(window frame). Each View has a minimum size and a maximum size. Is there a general algorithm to solve this kind of problems. My current code does not look elegant although it works for most of the situations, i some times get into situations where i have empty rects(unoccupied regions) or overlapped rects (views overlapped). I am sure someone has already solved this problem, i just cannot find any yet.

Thanks,
-Abhinay.

Comment: Are the rectangles all the same size or are they different sizes?

Comment: They are not same sized. They are resizable though. some of them are not resizable, but that can be considered a special case where minimum size is equal to maximum size. The rects are to be layed out and resized so that they fit the window leaving no empty spaces or overlapped spaces.

Comment: Is the number of views fixed? Are you trying to line the views up into columns?

Comment: no the number is not always fixed, views get added and removed. when a view is removed the other views would annex the removed view's area.

Answer (score 1):

Often what is used is recursive subdivision, alternating horizontal and vertical directions. This is eg how Eclipse IDE works. Normally it is assumed that views or windows can grow arbitrarily large, they are then padded if there is not enough content.